Hibernate native query works slow
I have a regular easy SQL query to SingleStore db
SELECT ses.created_on, ses.update_on, ses.job_id, ses.ip
FROM session ses
WHERE ses.created_on != ses.updated_on
AND ses.updated_on >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :threshold SECOND)
AND ses.created_on <= :endDate
AND ses.updated_on >= :startDate

The time for a direct request is 1.6 seconds, but when I try to use it with @Query and native=true, it takes 30 seconds+. It has about 1.5 million elements. Is it okay? How can I optimize it?
I have tried something like that
@Query(value = """SELECT ses.created_on, ses.update_on, ses.job_id, ses.ip
FROM session ses
WHERE ses.created_on != ses.updated_on
AND ses.updated_on >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :threshold SECOND)
AND ses.created_on <= :endDate
AND ses.updated_on >= :startDate", nativeQuery = true)
Set<Tuple> query (@Param("threshold") Long threshold, @Param("startDate") Instant startDate, @Param("endDate") Instant endDate);

default Set<Data> dataquery(Instant startDate, Instant endDate, Long threshold){
    query(threshHold, statDate, endDate)
        .stream()
        .map(tupl -> new Data(tupl.get("created_on", Timestamp.class).toInstant(), 
             tupl.get("updated_on", Timestamp.class).toInstant(), 
             tupl.get("job_id", Long.class), 
             tupl.get("ip", String.class)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}


I have tried using a Projection object instead of a Tuple, but it is still too slow. The problem is just inside the "query" method, not because of the stream inside the "data query." Only the "query" method executes for about 30 seconds.
Now I'm trying to use just regular Connection. PreparedStatement and ResultSet but still 20-25sec

Do any other queries suffer performance issues?  If JDBC is still slow - profile the query itself. It could be the connection from where your Spring service is running to the database, the setup of that connection etc - not necessarily anything to do with the query

"It has about 1.5 million elements. Is it okay" - And you see all of these 1.5 million results when doing the direct request, or is there a preconfigured limit on the number of results returned?

No. I'm using idea for connection to db. And it is 500 elements by page. So do you want to say that this 1,6 sec direct query is only for 500 elements? Because when I go to the next page it will be another query?

That is how pagination usually works, yes. I can't say how the IDE does it under water but based on the results you are getting, it seems pretty obvious that the resultset is being limited.
